# Numbers in OS X Error Log

Tags: macos

What do the +30 after the method(CFRelease) mean?

```
0   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff810a785e CFRelease + 30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that this line refers to a code position 30 bytes after the beginning of CFRelease.

Comment: Is there a technical term to describe these numbers?